# add smooth scrolling and scroll spy function to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

I have built a side list menu that needs to smooth scroll and scroll spy to different sections of the page. My links jump to the anchor link, but I can't seem to get smooth scroll and scroll spy to work. I'm using bootstrap and wordpress.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="page-menu">
  <ul class="page-menulist">
    <li class="menuitem active">
      <a href="#S1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem">
      <a href="#S2"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem">
      <a href="#S3"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem">
      <a href="#S4"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem">
      <a href="#S5"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem">
      <a href="#S6"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Add smooth scrolling to all links
   $("a").on('click', function(event) {

     // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
     if (this.hash !== "") {
       // Prevent default anchor click behavior
       event.preventDefault();

       // Store hash
       var hash = this.hash;

       // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
       // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
       }, 800, function() {

         // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
         window.location.hash = hash;
       });
     } // End if
   });
 });
```

Comment: It's hard to debug code when the problem is not reproduced. Could you create a [mcve] of your problem using the snippet tool or the snippet website of your choice?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: also note the documentation;

> #### Requires Bootstrap nav
>
> Scrollspy currently requires the use of a [Bootstrap nav component](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) for proper highlighting of active links.

You'll need to add the `nav` class to your `UL` (`<ul class="nav page-menulist">`) to take advantage of link highlighting.

And you can use [data-attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-2) to enable ScrollSpy against your menu (`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">` with a target **ID** `<div class="page-menu" id="navbar">` on the `page-menu` div. ).

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menuitem a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
section div {
  padding: 250px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}
section div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: purple;
}
section div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
section div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
section div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: darkviolet;
}
section div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
section div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: darkorchid;
}
.page-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.nav.page-menulist {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav.page-menulist .menuitem a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.nav.page-menulist .menuitem.active {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.nav.page-menulist .menuitem.active > a {
  color: darkorchid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">

  <div class="page-menu" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav page-menulist">
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S1">ONE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S2">TWO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S3">THREE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S4">FOUR</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S5">FIVE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#S6">SIX</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section>
    <div id="S1">
      ONE
    </div>

    <div id="S2">
      TWO
    </div>

    <div id="S3">
      THREE
    </div>

    <div id="S4">
      FOUR
    </div>

    <div id="S5">
      FIVE
    </div>

    <div id="S6">
      SIX
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```